# UITabBarItem default with custom title

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I am trying this for a while now, I do have a UiTabBar with three elements in my swift iOS app and I would like to use default images every TabBarItem, but combined with a custom title. It is not possible to do this in the StoryBoard, so I try to do this for every element in the ViewControllerClass of every page. Just one example:

```
self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.bookmarks, tag: 0)
self.tabBarItem.title = "Test"
```

Does anybody of you know a trick how to combine both of it? It seems like it's not possible to combine default images and custom titles...

Comment: yes, It impossible, so you can only use `UITabBarItem(title: String?, image: UIImage?, tag: Int)` to create tab with image and title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem/systemitem):

> The title and image of system tab bar items cannot be changed.

Presumably, this is because Apple likes apps to be consistent. They don't want users to be confused by seeing a common system Icon that doesn't do what it's expected to do.